# Netbeans error "not all the modules can be enabled"

Tags: netbeans-7

I am having problem in running a file in netbeans. I have been using netbeans 7.3 to run PHP code till today and so far it used to work perfectly. Suddenly, today when I first time tried to open a php file it simply did not open anything, neither showed any error. I tried reinstalling, but again no change. I noticed that if I try to create a new project then it shows me this message `This feature is not yet enabled. Press Next to activate it`. And I clicked next and it shows `Not all requested modules can be enabled`...and a very long message.
I again uninstalled. removed caches and library for netbeans. Installed again and on first opening it showed me this warning

`Warning - could not install some modules: org.apache.commons.logging - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-logging.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.logging org.apache.ws.commons.util - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-ws-commons-util.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.ws.commons.util org.apache.commons.io - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-io.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.io org.apache.commons.codec - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-codec.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.codec org.apache.commons.httpclient - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-httpclient.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.httpclient org.apache.xmlrpc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-xmlrpc.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.xmlrpc org.eclipse.equinox.common - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-common.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.common org.eclipse.core.jobs - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-jobs.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.jobs org.eclipse.equinox.registry - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-registry.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.registry org.eclipse.equinox.app - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-app.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.app org.eclipse.equinox.preferences - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-preferences.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.preferences org.eclipse.core.contenttype - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-contenttype.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.contenttype org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-runtime-compatibility-auth.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.auth org.eclipse.core.runtime - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-runtime.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.runtime org.eclipse.equinox.security - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-equinox-security.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.equinox.security org.eclipse.core.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-core-net.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.core.net org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.core org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-repositories-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.repositories.core org.apache.commons.lang - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-apache-commons-lang.jar: Not found bundle:org.apache.commons.lang org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-net.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.net org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-commons-xmlrpc.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.commons.xmlrpc org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-tasks-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.tasks.core org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-mylyn-bugzilla-core.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla.core com.jcraft.jzlib - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/com-jcraft-jzlib.jar: Not found bundle:com.jcraft.jzlib com.jcraft.jsch - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/com-jcraft-jsch.jar: Not found bundle:com.jcraft.jsch org.eclipse.jgit - org.netbeans.InvalidException: Netigso: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 7.3.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/ide/modules/org-eclipse-jgit.jar: Not found bundle:org.eclipse.jgit`.

I spent almost a day on this. I am using netbeans 7.3. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

Open the netbeans.conf file and comment out the *netbeans_jdkhome="/usr"* line.
It worked on my Linux system.

Comment: on Unix this is found in the /etc directory, not the home directory.  Note this netbeans.conf is a file, and not a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. Solution is very simply: reinstall NetBeans and when installation manager will ask JDK path, set path to one of your JDK (use selector in menu). Default path "/usr/" or other which IDE set automatically is not actual and after installation you'll cann't change default path!